# Post method with axios and spring

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios

I am new in vue.js.I am looking for how to save the data of a form with axios in a database.I work with spring and thymeleaf template engine.

Here are my code :

Html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <h1>TEST FORM</h1>
     <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Type description: <input type="text" v-model="description" /></p>
        <p><button v-on:click="addType()"> Send </button><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>


 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
     Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
      new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                 description: ' '
            },
           methods:{
             addType(){
               var vm = this;
               this.$http.post('/insert', {
                    body:vm.description
               }).then(response => {})
            }
         }
      }); 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I declared the description field NOT NULL in my table and when I execute this code I have this exception in the console:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT     NULL constraint failed: type.description)
```

I suppose it’s the value entered in the form field that is not retrieved. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my insert method using spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void createType(@ModelAttribute Type type) {
         if(Objects.equals(type.getDescription(), "")) {
             throw new NullPointerException("The description should not be empty.");
         }
         typeService.createType(type);
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createTypeForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("insertType", new Type());
        return "insertType";
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use URLSearchParams() function for making post object like below

```
var postdata = new URLSearchParams();
postdata.append('name',value);
axios.post("url-where-to-post",postdata).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `post` method's body should be under a `data` property and you should access the description of your Vue instance as `this.description`:

```
this.$http.post('/insert', {
  data: this.description
}).then(response => {})
```

Hope this helps!